# Issue in running a script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have created a script in */home/prashast* directory. I've created another directory inside */home/prashast* named *TestDirectory*. I've multiple files inside */home/prashast/TestDirectory*. While running a script from */home/prashast* directory its not effecting the files in */home/prashast/TestDirectory*.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(ls /home/prashast/TestDirectory/); do
     mv "$f.txt" "$f.text";
done
```

Comment: When i am writing echo $f i am able to see all the files in the directory but i could not rename the files inside the directory. and getting the error "mv: cannot stat ‘file1.txt.txt’: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls` result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/72456), use this code instead.

```bsh
for f in /home/prashast/TestDirectory/*; do
    echo mv "$f" "${f%.*}.text";
done
```

The `${f%.*}` that we used is a shell parameter expansion expression (cut-up-to-first-suffix); stripping start from end to the begging of filename till first `.` seen.

Read chapter on [Bash shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for more.

Comment: Could you please explain ${f%%.*}

Comment: Is there any benefit to quoting the path in this?  Like:  `for f in "/home/prashast/TestDirectory/*"`  I always want to do it thinking it's going to help with special characters in the filenames but I don't see many people do that so I'm guessing there is no real benefit to it?

Comment: for me is difficult to answer your this question, but basically as my experience mostly `for loop` is using for one level of path and only including files to process,  so `*` can do the job for any matching file and if it's two or more levels can be `/*/*` in path and inside `for... ` can decide the other processes.